# How many certificates need for IdentityServer3?

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver3

So based on the [documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/crypto.html) IdentityServer3 server must be setup for SSL and also it needs X.509 certificate to perform cryptography. (like token signing).

Does that mean we have to install 2 different certificates on the hosting server? or just one for both SSL &  token encryption? (I'm not sure if latter is even possible)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need two certificates, one for SSL and one for signing. These should be on the hosting server in you certificate store.

These certificates have different purposes, lifetimes and usage policies, etc. I wouldn't combine them.

You can get away with using a long lived, self-signed certificate for the signing certificate, created for example with openssl or makecert. You don't have to go to a CA for this one.

Comment: And here's a link on how to use makrcert for the signing cert: https://brockallen.com/2015/06/01/makecert-and-creating-ssl-or-signing-certificates/